# Is there an eclipse plugin for Play2?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, playframework-2.0

I know there is one for play1, but I don't find any for play2.

I hope the plugin can compile the templates to scala code automatically. It's not convenient now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Edit**: This answer is outdated. A Play Eclipse plugin has been written, as @Baztoune says.

There is no Play 2 plugin for Eclipse at the time I’m writing these lines. However, there is an `eclipsify` sbt command, provided by the Play 2 sbt plugin, which is able to generate an Eclipse project from a Play 2 application.

You won’t get syntax highlighting, contextual completion or code navigation inside Play 2 templates, but you can have them to be automatically compiled when saved by using the `~run` sbt command (instead of just `run`). Check the Eclipse “General −> Workspace −> Refresh using native hooks or polling” option is enabled so it will take compiled templates changes into account.

Comment: Downvoting because answer is severely outdated.

Answer (score 36):

I just came across [Scala IDE Play2](https://github.com/scala-ide/scala-ide-play2/wiki) plugin for Eclipse Indigo/Juno and Scala IDE. The current features are

- Syntax Highlighting (routes and templates)
- Code completion (templates)
- Formatter (routes)
- Hyperlinking (routes and templates)

Note that hyperlinking to Java files is not supported for now. Also there are some limitations for the code completion feature, just take some time to read the doc. I didn't try it myself as I'm not working with Play2 right now, but thought it might be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, here's how to get started:

1. Find the correct update site for your version of Eclipse from http://scala-ide.org/download/current.html.
2. In Eclipse go to ***Help***->***Install New Software***. Use the update site from above to locate Scala related plugins.
3. Install both the *Scala IDE for Eclipse* plugin and the *Play2 support in Scala IDE* plugin. Note that the *Play2 support in Scala IDE* plugin is listed under the *Scala IDE plugins* checkbox.

[image]

I was unable to get this working at all starting from bare Eclipse, as many sources have suggested doing. The problem seems to be incompatible dependencies that only show up after much wasted time. The Scala IDE route eliminated this problem.

Comment: this worked for me -- really odd that at this level of maturity in the framework the tools are so crude. as a general rule it seems like the java world is usually way further ahead in that sense. Like, why is the app itself still run from outside of Eclipse? I guess you can configure it yourself but I do a lot of corporate Java dev & all the web stuff shows up neatly in the "Servers" tab... odd that Play should consider itself an exception given that it is trying to be so developer friendly

Answer (score 7):

Yes. That's Scala IDE.

Update Site for Eclipse Juno and Kepler: http://download.scala-ide.org/sdk/e38/scala210/stable/site

Install with the following features:

- Scala IDE for Eclipse
- Scala IDE Plugins (incubation)

Answer (score 6):

I use Scala IDE from http://scala-ide.org/ , then eclipsify my play2 project and import.

It works like a charm: it compiles my scala/java code.

You can get more details at this URL http://scala-ide.org/docs/tutorials/play20scalaide20/index.html

Comment: I did the same, but I hope it can convert "*.scala.html" to scala too.