# Eclipse plugin for play 2

Tags: eclipse-plugin, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am a beginner with Play2 framework and Scala.

Is there any eclipse play 2 plugin available?

If yes, then please provide me the link for the same. I am used to Eclipse and have never used Scala before;hence in a confusion like how and where to start from. Looking at the Play2 Doc, sems like working in command prompt IDE which is very difficult (though I have tried yet)

Please let me know the eclipse plugin for Play2 or some other IDE helpful for this.

Regards,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an eclipse plugin for Play2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287994/is-there-an-eclipse-plugin-for-play2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There in no plugin as such for Eclipse.

Play! framework has nice set of tools for doing tasks such as following

- creating new play project
- running the project
- deployment of the application
- doing the continuous testing mode etc

Trust me, once you start using this, you gonna love it.

Beside you do not require any experience in Scala, as for Play framework you can use Java language, if you are comfortable with it (you can choose Java template while creating new Play project )
and also you can use IDE for syntax highlighting , code completion etc

Comment: I will use Java language for the Play2 framework. You might be using some IDE for writing the codes and getting other IDE helps such as syntax highlighting, code completion, etc. I am not aware of the IDE to use for Play2 framework. I want to know which IDE shall I use to add the Play2 plugin and for using Java language?

Comment: As of now, There is no IDE / plugin which has support for Play! framework.  But @andrewf in other answer is mentioned IntelliJ will Support in next version.

Comment: where can I learn the basics of play framework? Please don't tell to learn from documentation, its really very tough to read every line of documentation and a huge one too :(

Comment: If you satisfied with any of these answers then please accept.
and thats the another question you asking but here are the pointers : 
[James Ward presentation at JavaOne](http://goo.gl/0k9A1),
[Notes on Basics](http://goo.gl/Px5wF), (http://goo.gl/k0A41)

Answer (score 1):

I had a brief try of Play development using Eclipse and the Scala Plugin. I personally found it awkward and not terribly helpful. (The errors which the IDE reported were not always the same as the ones that the Play compiler reported, for example.)

I’ve had a lot more joy using the Intellij IDEA IDE, with its Scala plugin. As with Eclipse the current version of IDEA does not have specific support for Play Framework 2, but it does have specific support for Scala.

The next version of Intellij IDEA, v12, *will* have explicit support for Play Framework 2: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/index.html#Frameworks_Support (but only in the paid-for ‘Ultimate’ edition, not in the free ‘Community’ edition).

Comment: I will be using Java language while using Play2 framework. Can you suggest what are the possible options from the IDE prospective i.e. which all IDE can I use for this (Since you already faced problems with Eclipse hence I am eager to know about all the possible options)

Comment: You can use the IDE of your choice. As you going to import the generated IDE files from Play! and use IDE.

Refer this link for documentation: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/IDE